# MySQL Upgrade Issue

Tags: server, mysql

I ran the commands `apt update` and `apt upgrade` to make sure everything is updated. MySQL could not upgrade because of this error:

```
Error occurred: The mysql.session exists but is not correctly configured. The mysql.session needs SELECT privileges in the performance_schema database and the mysql.db table and also SUPER privileges.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 5
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I don't know why that error appears. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It's been a while, but did you ever solve this problem?  The answer provided by stefan below requires that the service is still running, but from your question it seems that the MySQL service is not running anymore, so it's not possible to change tables or rows in them.

Comment: @LifeBoy It's been a long time but I think the MySQL service was running. I had two mysql.session users, one with the hostname localhost and one with 127.0.0.1. I deleted the user mysql.session@127.0.0.1, flushed the privileges and everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on an Ubuntu 16.04 system. The problem on my system was a 2nd **mysql.session** user entry (mysql.session@%) in the user table. Others report that there might be also a **mysql.session@127.0.0.1** entry. Make sure you have only the **mysql.session@localhost** user present.

After cleaning up flush the privileges and run `apt upgrade` again.